How does an AppWidgetProvider access the RemoteViews passed to AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()
The app activity responsible for an appwidget can call
AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(int appWidgetId, RemoteViews views).
As a result the
AppWidgetProvider gets its
onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,  int[] appWidgetIds) method called.
What happens to the RemoteViews? In every example that I have seen, the AppWidgetProvider constructa its own RemoteViews. If my AppWidgetProvider wants to use the RemoteViews passed to updateAppWidget(),
how does it access that one?

OK, the documentation isn't very clear here.
AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()
should in fact be called by the AppWidgetProvider itself,
and causes the actual widget on the screen to be updated according to the RemoteViews passed. So my question should really have been
How does an activity cause its widget's onUpdate() to get called? This question may be answered elsewhere: if not, I'll post it.
